# Solve Linear Least Squares (Using the Gradient)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

In Least Square optimization,
A=\begin{pmatrix}
     1 & t_1 & t_1^2 & \cdots & t_1^k \\
     1 & t_2 & t_2^2 & \cdots & t_2^k \\
     \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
     1 & t_n & t_n^2 & \cdots & t_n^k    
     \end{pmatrix}
b=**\begin{pmatrix}
        s_1 \\
        s_2  \\
        \vdots\\
s_n\\
        \end{pmatrix}**
c=\begin{pmatrix}
        x_0 \\
        x_1  \\
        \vdots\\
x_n\\
        \end{pmatrix}

$f(x_0,x_1,...,x_n)=\left\lVert b-Ax\right\rVert ^2=b.b-2A^Tb.x+x.A^TAx$.

In this how is $\nabla f(x)$ calculated. I know how to calculate gradient vector, but here with matrix notation I don't understand how in the book they have simply written it as $\nabla f(x)=-2A^Tb+2A^TAx$.

Also then they go on to show Hessian=$2A^TA$ is positive definite. I don't understand this part. Since $t_1,t_2, ..,t_n$ are distinct A has columns which are linearly independent so if $Ax=0$ then $x=0$.  Then since $x.A^TAx=\left\lVert Ax\right\rVert^2 $ they say that Hessian is positive definite.

Why is the columns of A being **linearly independent** important?

I don't understand how they say Hessian is positive definite by $x.A^TAx=\left\lVert Ax\right\rVert^2 $

Can someone please explain this to me

Comment: Linear dependency in this case is important so as to have unique closed form solution which is given by $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$
  f_1(x) = b\cdot b ~,~~ f_2(x) = (A^T b)\cdot x ~,~~ f_3(x) = x\cdot(A^T A x)
$$
We can write these in terms of components (with summation over repeated indices implied) as
$$
  f_1(x) = b_i b_i ~,~~ f_2(x) = A_{ij} b_i x_j ~,~~ f_3(x) = A_{ij} A_{ik} x_j x_k \,.
$$

**Gradient**

The gradient is defined as
$$
  [\nabla f(x)]_p = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_p}
$$
Therefore
$$
  \begin{align}
  [\nabla f_1(x)]_p = \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_p} &= 0 \\
  [\nabla f_2(x)]_p = \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_p} &= A_{ij} b_i \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_p} = A_{ij} b_i \delta_{jp} = A_{ip} b_i \\
  [\nabla f_3(x)]_p = \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_p} &= A_{ij} A_{ik} \left[\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_p} x_k +  x_j \frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x_p}\right]= A_{ij} A_{ik} \left[ \delta_{jp} x_k + x_j \delta_{kp}\right] = A_{ip} A_{ik} x_k + A_{ij} A_{ip} x_j \\
   &= 2A_{ip} A_{ij} x_j
  \end{align}
$$
Going back to matrix notation,
$$
  \nabla f_1(x) = 0 ~,~~ \nabla f_2(x) = A^T b ~,~~ \nabla f_3(x) = 2 A^TAx \,.
$$
Therefore
$$
  \nabla f(x) = -2 A^T b + 2 A^T A x \,.
$$

**Hessian**

The Hessian is defined as
$$
 [\nabla\nabla f(x)]_{pq} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_p \partial x_q} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_q}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_p}\right)
$$
Repeating the process that we used for the gradient,
$$
  \begin{align}
  [\nabla\nabla f_2(x)]_{pq} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_q} (A_{ip} b_i) = 0 \\
  [\nabla\nabla f_3(x)]_{pq} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_q} (
   2A_{ip} A_{ij} x_j) = 2A_{ip} A_{ij} \delta_{jq} = 2A_{ip} A_{iq}
  \end{align}
$$
Therefore
$$
  \nabla\nabla f(x) = 2 A^T A \,.
$$

**Positive definite**

You have to show that
$$
  t = z \cdot ( A^T A z) > 0
$$
Once again, going to component notation,
$$
  t = z_p A_{ip} A_{iq} z_q = (Az)\cdot(Az) = \lVert Az \rVert^2
$$
which is positive unless $Az = 0$. You now have to exclude the case where $Az = 0$, which you have done by invoking linear independence.  Therefore, the Hessian is positive definitive.

Comment: what is $\delta_{jq}$.

Comment: @Biswajit Banerjee shouldn't $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_p}$ be  $2A_{i(p+1)} A_{ij} x_j$

Comment: $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta with value 1 when $i=j$ and 0 otherwise. @sam_rox I'm not sure how you would get $A_{i(p+1)}$, $p$ is just an index and the algebra is simple enough that one can do it mechanically.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee If we are differentiating with respect to say $x_2$ then p=2, and we have the terms like $t_1^2$ which acts as $A_{ip}$ right? But terms $t_1^2,t_2^2..$ are in $A_{1,3},A_{2,3},A_{3,3}...$ indexes right.So shouldn't it be $A_{i(p+1)}$

Comment: @sam_rox : The contents of $A$ are not relevant because they are constants as far as the differentiation is concerned.  One way to see that is to use a 2x2 or 3x3 matrix and work out the details by hand.